# Bluetooth: Android 6 & 7 Sniff mode

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing a custom FW on STM32, which communicates over Bluetooth classic with Android device.

It worked flawlessly with Android 5. But starting from Android 6, the Sniff mode is requested by Android and its values are out of the range for our use cases.

We tried to exit sniff mode immediately after Android requested Sniff mode. This didn't help, because after next 5 seconds, Android will request the sniff mode again.

Similarly, when we set our sniff values, Android will ignore them and request its own "big" values.

We have under control Android App and FW on the Bt device. Is there any way
to control sniff mode from Android side? As far as I know there is no public API for doing that. Just asking if I missed something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the issue as well. The only solution that seems to work is using a "keep alive", whereby we send arbitrary data over the bluetooth socket every 1.5 seconds or so from the Android device. This seems to keep sniff mode from re-enabling.